# Проблема с Manim. При попытке сделать график значений числа ейлера, то выдает ошибку: ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: математика

```
self.axes = Axes()
self.f = lambda x: (1+1/x)**x
curve = self.axes.plot(self.f, color= RED)
self.play(Create(self.axes), Create(curve))
self.interactive_embed()
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый раз вижу эту библиотеку. Но судя по документации и [примерам](https://3b1b.github.io/manim/getting_started/example_scenes.html), может быть нужно просто задать координатную сетку такую, чтобы исключить из неё `0` по оси `x`, чтобы не было деления на ноль при вычислении функции:

```
self.axes = Axes((1, 10), (2, 3))
```

Comment: А если мне нужен график с -10 до 10 по обеим осям?